# Падает телеграмм бот на heroku

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegram, heroku, telegraf

Телеграмм бот на NodeJS + telegrafJS деплоится на heroku, бот работает корректно, но спустя неопределенное количество времени - падает и требует перезагрузки для дальнейшей работы, например функция `setTimeout()` прекращает отсчёт.

 Procfile выглядит следующим образом:
`worker: node index.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У heroku такая фишка, что если нет активности, то сервер "засыпает". По идеи это решается платным аккаунтом. 
Я делал telegram бота на laravel и тоже деплоил его heroku. У меня после того как сервер "заснул", первый запрос на бота обрабатывается немного дольше обычно, но дальше все отлично.